# Using exact same covariates in CBPS model and regression model

Tags: propensity-scores, covariate-balance

When using CBPS in R and following Imai and Ratkovic, do you necessarily need to include **all** the covariates in your covariate-balancing procedure that you are planning to use in the subsequent regression model? Or just the subset that provides the best 'prop.score' as displayed in a bal.plot?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, weighting does all the work of adjusting for covariates, and regression serves just to increase the precision of the effect estimate by reducing variability in the outcome. So you should adjust for all variables using weights, and include in your outcome regression model just a subset of those variables that increase precision of the effect estimate (i.e., pre-treatment covariates strongly predictive of the outcome).

Any variable you don't balance on but do include in the outcome regression model is a variable you are asking your audience to simply trust that you have adequately adjusted for. By attempting to balance and assessing balance on all covariates that you need to adjust for, you can provide confidence to your audience that you have adequately adjusted for those variables. You must assess balance in a broad and complete way (i.e., more than just standardized mean differences) to achieve this benefit, which is the whole point of weighting in the first place. The outcome regression model is optional; the covariate balance induced by the weights is not.

I'm not sure what you mean by "the subset that provides the best 'prop.score' as displayed in a bal.plot". Do you mean the subset that makes it so the distributions of the propensity score in the treatment groups look the same as demonstrated in a kernel density plot produced by `cobalt::bal.plot()`? Whether a propensity score is well balanced has nothing to do with whether the covariates are balanced because it is easy to balance on a poorly performing propensity score without balancing the covariates. You should find the propensity score specification that yields the best balance on all the *covariates* you need to adjust for; often this will involve including all those covariates in the propensity score model, as well as transformations of them (e.q., squares, cubes, and interactions). It us rarely worth looking at the balance of the propensity score except to diagnose the cause of the failure to balance the covariates.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. You were correct in your final paragraph about what I meant; though now I'm realizing some misunderstandings of mine. I had thought that the balance of the propensity score was the most important ultimate goal; but if I interpret you correctly, it's really the balance of each individual covariate themselves that are of most importance. Can you clarify exactly what you mean in your last sentence about diagnosing the cause of failure to balance the covariates?

Comment: Glad this was helpful. I mean that if your method fails to balance the PS, it will likely fail to balance the covariates, so if you see imbalance remaining in the covariates, it might be that you have a good PS but but balance wasn't achieved on it. But good balance on a PS does not imply good covariate balance. The reason balance on the PS is not sufficient is you can have a bad PS that is incorrectly specified; balancing it will not eliminate bias. Read [Ho, Imai, King and Stuart (2007)](https://doi.org/10.1093/pan/mpl013) for this perspective (the "propensity score tautology").

Comment: That is additionally clarifying, thank you. Two final questions (thanks again): (1) is there a convention/rule of thumb for what constitutes good balance? In terms of ASMD, I have seen 0.10 and 0.25 used as thresholds but no one true "rule". (2) What would be a potential explanation/diagnostic for the opposite case of the one you mention (specifically, what if the PS has poorer balance than all/most of the individual covariates)?

Comment: 1) There is no rule. Get them as low as possible. See the reference above. Prioritize balance on prognostically important covariates. 2) The opposite case doesn't imply anything.